# How can I alter the output for the sql desc command?

Tags: sqlplus

When I do desc table, I get back the columns Name, Null? and Type.  What I also wish to get back is a column like UNIQUE to tell me if the column is in fact unique.  I realize that this is a combination of columns labeled UNIQUE with the column (if present) labeled as the primary key for that table.

As an alternative, I have tried:

```
SELECT 
column_name "Name", 
nullable "Null?",
concat(concat(concat(data_type,'('),data_length),')') "Type"
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name='TABLE_NAME_TO_DESCRIBE';
```

which I found somewhere, however I get 0 rows returned when I replace the TABLE_NAME_TO_DESCRIBE with the name of my table.

I am running from sqlplus.  Any way to accomplish this?  Either specific (returning of UNIQUE constraint) or general (how to alter desc command results) answers appreciated.

Comment: TABLE_NAME_TO_DESCRIBE is case sensitive

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that might be what was tripping me, but alas I get 0 rows either way with the query above.  However, you did jog my mind and I see I was not logged in as a user with sufficient enough permissions.  I now get 10 rows with that query, so that solves expanding the returned columns.  However, I still do not see how I can list if a column is UNIQUE or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT utc.column_name "Name"
   , utc.nullable "Null?"
   , concat(concat(concat(utc.data_type,'('),utc.data_length),')') "Type"
   , ui.uniqueness
FROM user_tab_columns utc 
LEFT JOIN user_ind_columns uic ON uic.table_name = utc.table_name 
   AND utc.column_name = uic.column_name
LEFT JOIN user_indexes ui ON ui.table_name = utc.table_name
   AND uic.index_name=ui.index_name
WHERE utc.table_name='TABLE_NAME_TO_DESCRIBE';
```

Comment: I see, I have to ultimately make it over to the user_indexes table.  Thanks!  It is a nice extension of the standard desc available to me.